# how to find max of datetime value of each group in group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
user_id UserName    created_on                 dateTime
189 essa amuel      2011-08-26 16:31:13.750    2011-11-08 10:13:49.000
189 essa amuel      2011-08-26 16:31:13.750    2011-11-14 16:38:54.000
19  kessa samuel    2011-08-26 16:31:13.750    2011-11-18 12:56:50.000
19  kessa samuel    2011-08-26 16:31:13.750    2011-11-22 14:12:56.000
```

How to get user latest login time for each user by group by clause on userid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT USERNAME, MAX([dateTime]) FROM tablename GROUP BY USERNAME
```

is that not it?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT user_id, UserName, last_login = MAX([datetime])
FROM dbo.table
GROUP BY user_id, UserName;
```

As an aside, you shouldn't use reserved words like `datetime` as column names.

Comment: And mixing `CamelCase` with `separated_by_underscores` and `mixedCase` is not good practise.

Comment: Can I be able to rank with in the group in group by

Comment: Please edit the question or ask another one with specific details, including what you mean by rank and what the expected output would be.